# shifting words in a sentence to clarify emphasis

Tags: sentence-construction

What other words can be used ,similarly to  ‘only’, i.e. position shifting , to change meaning/emphasis? I have just seen actually, and just …

Comment: Can you give an example of a sentence and what meaning/emphasis you want? Currently this question is very vague.

Answer (score 0):

- Were you late? [simple question]
- You were *late*? [question expressing surprise at tardiness
  ]
- You *were* late? [question expressing surprise at tardiness, though it seemed the person would be on time]
- *You* were late? [question expressing surprise at this particular person's tardiness]

Not only is the word order important, but *stress* or *emphasis* placed on a word can alter the meaning.

Studying English can be *stressful*.

Answer (score 0):

Most adverbs can be moved around in a sentence to change the emphasis.

> It's not really difficult
> It's not difficult, really
> Really, it's not difficult
> It's really not difficult

Only has additional flexibility because it can also be used as an adjective.